# Mongoose Static is not working on Nest.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

This is the schema I declared

**cat.schema.ts**

```
@Schema()
export class Cat extends Document {
    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    age: number;

    @Prop()
    breed: string;
}

// interfaces for statics and methods 
interface CatStatics {
    findByAge: (age: number) => Cat[]
}

interface CatMethods {
    findByName: (name: string) => Cat[]
}


export type CatDocument = Cat & Document & CatMethods;
export type CatModel = Model<CatDocument> & CatStatics;


export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);


CatSchema.statics = {
    findByAge: function (age: number) {
        return this.find({ age })
    }
}

CatSchema.methods = {
    findByName: async function (name: string): Promise<Cat[]> {
        const model = this.model(Cat.name) as CatModel;
        let cat: Cat[] = await model.find({ name })
        return cat;
    }
}
```

**cat.service.ts**

```
 // this methods is working 
 const cat = new this.catModel();
 const result = await cat.findByName("abc")

// but this findByAge is not recongnized by my IDE
const data = await this.catModel.findByAge(12);
```

Thoug my methods is working but the `findByAge` is not recognized by my IDE, it says:
`Property 'findByAge' does not exist on type 'Model<CatDocument, {}, {}, {}, any>'.`

How can I solve this issue?

I tried multiple ways to implement static but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the type of `this.catModel`?

Comment: this is the model which I am using in cat services like this.:                                    
`constructor(@InjectModel("Cat") private catModel: Model<CatDocument>) { }`

Comment: Try changing the methods in `CatMethods` to be `static`